# Java setting folder owner so only the program have access to it

Tags: java, encryption, directory, file-permissions

I have an encryption program and I was looking for a way in so that only the encryption program have access to they keys folder. But setting it to the owner or anyone in the users aren't a good idea. I was thinking maybe something like Steam did with its folder. It restricted access even to the owner/admin of the computer and only the Steam app can communicate/edit/access the folder. I was wondering how to do it in Java.

The code that I currently have right now is this.

```
Path file = Paths.get("F:\\keys\\pic.datakey");
UserPrincipal owner = file.GetFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService()
        .lookupPrincipalByName("username");
Files.setOwner(file, owner);
```

with `keys` being the folder name and `pic.datakey` is the key that I'm trying to prevent anyone except the program to have access with.

> How to set the folder owner to the encryption program's?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What do you hope to achieve? If you want to do this as some sort of security measure, it's not a good one.

Comment: FYI, I can freely move/edit/copy items from my Steam folder. I wouldn't like it too if programs would disable that.

Comment: @Michael I just want to prevent users including the owner to have access to the keys folder and yes it's a security measure. I guess I'll note that.

to PieterDeBie there's a folder somewhere in C: drive I have to look for it first but you have no access to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encryption program is not a principal.  It cannot own things.  What you need is to run the program as some special principal<sup>1</sup>.

Problems:

1. What principal should you use?  There won't be a platform-independent answer to that.  Indeed, there isn't an obvious platform-specific answer, at least for Linux.
2. How do you ensure that the encryption program *runs* as the designated principal.  This is not solvable in Java.  (Long story ... but mechanisms like UNIX setuid will require a non-Java (non-shell) launcher to implement them securely for a Java program.)

But once you have done those things, it will be unnecessary to change the owner of the file (as per your code).  The owner will default to the principal under which the program is currently being run.

---

But here's the real question.  What do you think you will achieve by hiding the encryption keys from the user who has encrypted the file?

If we assume that the user has full "root" access (or equivalent) then they can access any file stored locally on the system, either directly (i.e. as root) or with some extra effort.  Certainly on a typical operating system.

And the flip-side is that if the user doesn't have "root" (or equivalent) access, you can stop him / her from seeing files by setting the owner / permissions of the files.  Adding encryption doesn't achieve a lot more.

> Yes it's a security measure.

Security against what?  The user who owns the machine?  Even assuming that it is technically feasible, is it a reasonable thing to do?

(These are rhetorical questions.  I am posing them for you to think about, not because I either agree or disagree with what you are doing.  And not because I want to debate this.)

---

<sup>1 - Suppose that the program runs as the user.  First of all a user cannot transfer ownership of his files to another user.  That would provide an easy way to "cheat" file usage accounting.  Your encryption program running as the user couldn't do that either.  (The OS cannot determine the *intent* of an operation.)  Second, assuming an ordinary user *could* change the owner of a file, then after the change of ownership the user would not be able to read it.  Moreover, neither could the encryption program.</sup>

Comment: Ok I'll have this noted. Well assuming the computer is being manipulated from someone else like if someone is "hacking" into the machine at least he doesn't have access to the folder. He would still have to enter some sort of password into the program so it's protected in a way assuming the person doesn't have the password at hand

Comment: Well, yea, but standard security thinking is that someone who has hacked a local account can probably get a "root" escalation relatively easily.  Maybe using an undisclosed "zero day" vulnerability, or maybe by exploiting an admin mistake, or social engineering.

Comment: Ok well thank you for not being that rude. I'll take note of this as well.

Comment: *"Ok well thank you for not being that rude."*  - Is that supposed to be a compliment?